# Estoy teniendo problemas con Crud con Spring

Tags: java, spring

Hola buenas tardes a todos, actualmente estoy intentando crear un crud con Spring y estoy teniendo el siguiente problema:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field service in com.example.appjava.Controlador required a bean of type 'com.example.appjava.PersonaService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.appjava.PersonaService' in your configuration.
```

Estas son las clases que tengo creadas:

AppjavaApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AppjavaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppjavaApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Controlador

```
package com.example.appjava;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200/", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/personas"})
public class Controlador {

    @Autowired
    PersonaService service;
    
    @GetMapping
    public List<Persona>Listar(){
        
        return service.listar();
        
    }
    
}
```

Persona

```
package com.example.appjava;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="Persona")
public class Persona {
    
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private String apellidos;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }
    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }
    
}
```

PersonaRepositorio

```
package com.example.appjava;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;

public interface PersonaRepositorio extends Repository<Persona, Integer>{
    
    List<Persona>findAll();
    Persona findOne(int id);
    Persona save(Persona p);
    void delete(Persona p);

}
```

PersonaService

```
package com.example.appjava;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
@Service
public interface PersonaService {
    
    
    List<Persona>listar();
    Persona listarId(int id);   
    Persona add(Persona p);
    Persona edit(Persona p);
    Persona delete(int id);

}
```

PersonaServiceImp

```
package com.example.appjava;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


public class PersonaServiceImp implements PersonaService{
    @Autowired(required = true)
    private PersonaRepositorio repositorio;
    
    @Override
    public List<Persona> listar() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return repositorio.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Persona listarId(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Persona add(Persona p) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Persona edit(Persona p) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Persona delete(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

He Buscado mil soluciones y ninguna me ayuda
Si me pudierais ayudar os lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Prueba anotar PersonaServiceImp con `@Service` y  PersonaRepositorio  con `@Repository` del paquete org.springframework.stereotype.Repository porque se ve que no se esta creando uno de esos 2 beans, porque spring debería mostrar un log mas detallado del error para analizar.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que puede ser porque es tu implementación de persona la que debes incluir en tu Controlador,

```
public class Controlador {

    @Autowired
    PersonaServiceImp service;
```

Por otro lado, en la etiqueta @Autowired el required por defecto es true, por lo que creo que puedes ahorrartelo en la la referencia al repositorio.

***EDITO***

Creo que también es necesario añadir la etiqueta en la implementación

```
@Service
public class PersonaServiceImp implements PersonaService{
```

Espero que te sirva
Un saludo

Comment: Da el mismo error, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
@Repository
public interface PersonaRepositorio extends JpaRepository<Persona, Integer>{
    
    List<Persona>findAll();
    Persona findOne(int id);
    Persona save(Persona p);
    void delete(Persona p);

}
```

Por lo que veo en tu código , te falta la directiva de @Repository en tu interfaz PersonaRepositorio , así mismo te recomiendo usar JpaRepository.

En PersonaServiceImpl prueba a ponerlo el atributo como private final , y a ponerla directiva de @Service , en vez de en la interfaz

```
@Service
public class PersonaServiceImp implements PersonaService{
    @Autowired
    private final PersonaRepositorio repositorio;
```

En el controlador debería quedar así, con la directiva @RestController y private final en el Autowired:

```
@RestController()
public class Controlador {

    @Autowired
   private final PersonaService service;
```